# Storing QByteArray data in QIODevice though write()

Tags: qt, qbytearray

Well i have a QIODevice where i want to store data. But have issues with it. Everytime i try to create one i get errors.

```
QIODevice dev;
dev.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
dev.write(md);
dev.close();
```

What i just want to store is a QByteArray (where you can use it with write(QByteArray) and then use it later.

Any idea?

The error is "cannot declare variable dev of abstract type 'QIODevice'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare variable of abstract type)). QIODevice is abstract. If you wanna use it you have to look at one of `Q3Socket, Q3SocketDevice, QAbstractSocket, QBuffer, QFile, QLocalSocket, QNetworkReply, and QProcess.`

I think best way for use is using QByteArray only.